# Not sure what I should use for "when"?

Tags: mandarin, vocabulary

Could I say

> 当我回家的时

for "when I was coming home"?

Comment: http://www.iciba.com/when

Answer (score 1):

If you use the adjectival '的', then it has to be '当我回家的时候' (at the time I come home) - *时候(time/ moment) is a noun*

If you don't use the adjectival '的' then you can write '当我回家时' (when I come home) - *时 (when) is an adverb*

当我回家的时候 = at the time I come home

当我回家时 = when I come home

当我正在回家的时候 = during the time I was coming home

当我正在回家时 = when I was coming home

Comment: Is 当 optional in the cases ending in 的时候?

Comment: @Ben Jackson  Yes, '当我回家的时候' = 'at the time I went home' ; '我回家的时候' = 'the time I went home' ; Since we can remove 'at '  in English, we can remove '当' in Chinese without changing the meaning of the sentence. Both 'at' and  '当' are already implied

Answer (score 0):

当我回家的时候 is OK

You can also do this without an explicit 'when'.

I saw a fox when I was coming home.
我看到一条狐狸，在我回家的路上。

When I was coming home, I saw a fox.
我在回家的路上看到一条狐狸。

I find it is not so easy to move things around in Chinese sentences.